# Incorrect long type

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, primitive-types

I have the following query in Hibernate:

```
val em: EntityManager = ...
em.createQuery("SELECT id FROM Segment s WHERE $condition", Long::class.java)
val result = q.resultList
```

When running it I get the following error:

```
Type specified for TypedQuery [long] is incompatible with query return type [class java.lang.Long]
```

Answer (score 7):

It looks like the `Long::class.java` is treated as unboxed and should be replaced with `Long::class.javaObjectType`

The working code is:

```
val em: EntityManager = ...
em.createQuery("SELECT id FROM Segment s WHERE $condition", Long::class.javaObjectType)
val result = q.resultList
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `java.lang.Long` instead of Kotlin’s `Long`.